# Создать строку из переменных (тупой вопрос)

Tags: php, строки, веб-программирование

```
$antwort = "$_POST['antwort'] $_POST['antwort2'] $_POST['antwort3']";
```

Выдаёт вот такую ошибку:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\ws\add.php on line 19

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Согласен с вами.

Comment: Значения нужно конкатинировать с помощью точки!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так:

```
$antwort = $_POST['antwort'] . ' ' . $_POST['antwort2'] . ' ' . $_POST['antwort3'];
```

Или так:

```
$antwort = "{$_POST['antwort']} {$_POST['antwort2']} {$_POST['antwort3']}";
```

или

```
$antwort = "$_POST[antwort] $_POST[antwort2] $_POST[antwort3]";
```

Answer (score 2):

Еще, как вариант, можно воспользоваться функцией [implode()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php). Она объединяет элементы массива в строку.